# Using PHP to create a web page without read access

Tags: php

This is a really open-ended and perhaps simple question, for which I apologize in advance.

I'm trying to create a web page that contains a link (or button or whatever) that will create another webpage (using a server-installed program that generates the page whenever called).  The problem is, the server interprets that as the user trying to write to the directory, and the user does not have write access for my tree.  The function that creates the page can also output to stddout, but I'm looking for some way to have that function generate the page and load it into the browser while denying the user (and thus the web page) write access to the directory.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  For reference, the program I am using is called Pygments and I am trying to generate color coded web pages whenever the button is clicked.  Pygments by default writes to stddout, but in practice is usually used to generate an HTML file which is then loaded.

Comment: If you don't need to save the page, why are you trying to write to the directory?  Why not just output the HTML to the browser?

Comment: Why are you generating a file every single time? Why not just append a class to the html tag via PHP, and use CSS to change the colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have one script that generates the page, and an .htaccess file that directs requests for non-existant pages to said script. eg: Your folder would look like:

```
myfolder/
  .htaccess
  index.php
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f #this rule skips the rewrite if the requested file actually exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d #this rule skips the rewrite if the requested directory actually exists
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?req=$1 [L,QSA]
```

index.php

```
<?php
if( !isset($_GET['req']) ) {
  die("no page requested.");
  // or whatever you want the default to be...
}

switch($_POST['req']) {
  case 'dogs.html':
    echo "dogs!";
    break;
  case 'cats.html':
    echo "cats!";
    break;
  default:
    echo "I don't know about that...";
}
```

and so you could request `http://mysite.com/myfolder/cats.html` without needing to actually write a file to that directory.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/file_write_php.htm

You must CHMOD 777 the file if it already exists. PHP shouldn't have any particular problem writing to a folder on its own.